# Return data type the same as class name via superclass?

Tags: java, oop

I have an `abstract` `class` which has one `abstract` method. I want this method to `return` the **same data type as the class which is overriding the method** without having to cast the result of `create` or having to make a new method declaration on each subclass. I want it to all be declared seemlessly from the parent class.

I want the method to return a object whose data type is the same as the class it was called on.

EDIT: I removed print as people are getting confused with what I am asking

```
abstract class A
{
   public abstract ... create();
}

class B extends A
{
   @override
   public ... create()
   {
      return new B...;
   }
}

class C extends A
{
   @override
   public ... create()
   {
      return new C...;
   }
}
```

Such that

```
B x1 = new B();
B x2 = x1.create();
// Since create was called on a B object
// a B object is returned, NOT AN "A" object

C y1 = new C();
C y2 = y1.create();
// create makes a C object this time,
// because it's called on a C object

// Problem: create() returns A object, even when
// called from class B or C.
// I want create() to return a B object if called from a B object.
```

What would be a good way of going about this? Thanks.

Comment: @Valentin I just made the print method to show that the return type of `create` completely depends on the subclass in which it is called. Overriding `print` from a superclass is not what I am trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is an easier way to do it than with [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45191542/3788176): just use a covariant return type in the subclass:

```
abstract class A {
  public abstract A create();
}

class B extends A {
  @Override public B create() {
    return new B...
  }
}
```

This is more pleasant if you are dealing with instances of `A`, since you don't have to make it generic (or, shudder, raw).

It also gives just as much of a guarantee that it returns a "self" type, i.e. no guarantee at all.

Comment: Is this legal? you are overriding a method with a different signature, surely? Then again, since `B`'s are of type `A`, it does make sense

Comment: @Hatefiend return type isn't part of the method signature. You are allowed to return a subtype of the return type of the parent method because that still conforms to the contract of the parent type.

Answer (score 5):

*I no longer think this is the right answer. It's **an** answer, but is over-complicated. See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45239150/3788176).*

There is no notion of a "self" type in Java's generics. The best you can do is to use self-bounded generics:

```
abstract class A<T extends A<T>>
{
   public abstract T create();
}
```

Then, in your subclasses:

```
class B extends A<B>
{
   @override
   public B create()
   {
      return new B...;
   }
}
```

Comment: Beat me. Luckily I saw your answer before starting to write down similar content ;-)

Comment: wow I really thought there would be a simpler solution without resorting to generics. Anyways thanks for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: This is the right way to go, upvoted. However, I find it disturbing that it's not bullet-proof: `class C extends A<B>` also works, but oh, hell...

Answer (score 0):

I have to question the design approach.

I'd be going for

```
abstract class A {
    abstract Supplier<? extends A> create();
}
```

with

```
class B extends A {
    public Supplier<B> create() {
        return B::new;
    }
}
```

(and C accordingly).
Then, there is

```
A b = new B();
A anotherB = b.create().get(); // will create a B
A c = new C();
A anotherC = c.create().get(); // will create a C
```

Comment: See my updated question. Removed the concept of printing because people are getting confused

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make your `create` method abstract.  If all the subclasses have a no-argument constructor, then you can just write this (in class `A`)

```
public A create() {
    try {
        return getClass().newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This checks the class of the object that you called the method on; and creates a new object of the same class, using its no-argument constructor.

**Update**

OP's comment suggests that they don't want to have to cast the returned value.  If this is a requirement, then the casting can be avoided by changing the method signature as follows.

```
public <T extends A> T create() {
    try {
        return getClass().newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow okay I think this is what I needed. So does `newInstance` call any kind of constructor? How does that work? I'm reading the documentation on it and it's a little confusing.

Comment: There needs to be a no-argument constructor in each subclass of `A`.  That's the one that will get called.  If you need to use a different constructor, things are a bit more complicated - you need to use something like `getClass().getConstructor( some stuff here ).newInstance( some stuff here);`.

Comment: The issue though is if this function is called on a `B` object, it may return a `B` object BUT to the caller, the `returned` data type will be `A`. Then I'm back to the issue of having to cast it to a `B`. That's not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

`this.getClass()` to get the class object, or, `this.getClass().getSimpleName()` to get a **string** of class name.

Comment: please see my updated question -- made it easier to understand